# What is the issue with my Javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was trying to make some object into objects , but there's a problem with my syntax.

That's the code:

```
var friends = {
    bill : {
    firstName:"Bill",
    lastName:"Gates",
    number:00158965478
    },
    steve :{

    firstName:"Steve",
    LastName:"Jobs"
    number:00125688977
    },
    Joe: {

    firstName:"Joe",
    LastName:"Erabti",
    number:0021625804429
    }

};
```

Comment: where's the problem ?

Comment: missing `,` after `LastName:"Jobs"`

Comment: You might try [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](http://eslint.org/). Many editors have plugins for them.

Comment: Yh right ^_^ I'm stupid .... thanks!  @itsgoingdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the comma after last names of Jobs.. So its suppose to be like this:

```
  var friends = {
        bill : {
        firstName:"Bill",
        lastName:"Gates",
        number:00158965478
        },
        steve :{
        firstName:"Steve",
        LastName:"Jobs", //<-- You previously forgot it here
        number:00125688977
        },
        Joe: {
        firstName:"Joe",
        LastName:"Erabti",
        number:0021625804429
        }

    };
```

Comment: Yh right I'm stupid !! thanks

Comment: Yep, Thanks. @Dsafds